# How to store output as variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I'm looking to store the hash of my most recently downloaded file in my downloads folder as a variable.

So far, this is what I have:

```
md5sum $(ls -t | head -n1) | awk '{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
user@ci-lux-soryan:~/Downloads$ md5sum $(ls -t | head -n1) | awk '{print $1}'
c1924742187128cc9cb2ec04ecbd1ca6
```

I have tried storing it as a variable like so, but it doesn't work:

```
VTHash=$(md5sum $(ls -t | head -n1) | awk '{print $1}')
```

Any ideas, where am I going wrong

Comment: How did that not work? Seems to work just fine when I tried...

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

As @Cyrus outlined parsing `ls` has its own pitfalls and therefore better to avoid it altogether rather than allowing unexpected corner cases. The following shall facilitate the requirements epitomised.

```sh
VTHash="$(find -type f -mtime 0 | tail -n 1 | xargs md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```